# Backbone setup with good class separation - App not defined error

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js, coffeescript

It's really easy to find docs on Backbone.js online, but not exactly easy to find tutorials or docs on how to set up Backbone in your project with good class separation. Most tutorials will just dump all the code in the doc ready function... not really into that.

I am trying to follow the backbone namespacing pattern found here (using coffeescript and not vanilla js) http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#namespace_convention

Here is my basic setup:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
                <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/white-skateapp-theme.css" /-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-mobile-overrides.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom-icons.css" />
                <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>

            <!-- SPOTS LIST -->
            <div data-role="page" id="spots">

                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Spots</h1>
                    <a href="#search" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="search" data-corners="false">search</a>
                </div><!-- /header -->

                <div data-role="content">   
                    spots list
                </div><!-- /content -->

                <!-- footer fixed bottom -->
                <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed">
                    <div data-role="navbar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#spots">Spots</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#me">Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#friends">Friends</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /navbar -->
                </div>


            </div><!-- /page -->

                <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>

                <!-- backbone -->
                <!-- backbone views -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/views/spots_list.js"></script>

                <!-- backbone app js file, not to be confused with phonegap app.whatever -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

                <!-- initialize the phonegap app -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.coffee

```
window.App =
  Models: {}
  Views: {}
  Collections: {}
  Routers: {}
    init: ->
      spotsList = new App.Views.SpotsList()


$ ->
  console.log "init"
  App.init()
```

spots_index.coffee

```
class App.Views.SpotsListView extends Backbone.View

  el: $ 'body'

  initialize: ->
    console.log "initialize called"
```

directory and project setup looks like this:

[image: image of folder structure]

The problem is that when document ready fires, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
```

Also get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'init' app.js:20
(anonymous function) app.js:20
fire jquery-1.8.2.js:974
self.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.js:1082
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.8.2.js:406
DOMContentLoaded
```

(btw, this project is done in Phonegap, coffeescript, backbone.js, and jQuery Mobile)

Comment: no, i think it got mangled somehow when pasting it over, updated it

Comment: @muistooshort anything about what i'm doing here seem wrong to you?

Comment: need to see the js , hard to debug coffeescript without proper indentation

Comment: yeah, that is sorta challenging. i was thinking i should just post the js and ignore coffee, but then the problem could be the coffee isn't properly formatted. problem solved below, thanks @camus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quote :

```
        <!-- backbone -->
        <!-- backbone views -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/views/spots_list.js"></script>

        <!-- backbone app js file, not to be confused with phonegap app.whatever -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

you need at least to call the app.js script before anything related to App , you cant call an object if you did not define it first. so the right

```
    <!-- backbone app js file, not to be confused with phonegap app.whatever -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- backbone -->
    <!-- backbone views -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/views/spots_list.js"></script>
```